# compiling YCM for vim under cygwin windows with visual studio and cmake

Tags: visual-studio, vim, compilation, cmake, cygwin

So,

I'm trying to compile YouCompleteMe plugin for vim in windows using visual studio as documented. The current cmake that ships with cygwin doesn't have a generator for visual studio so I installed the official cmake through an installer and copied all the nessecary files into cygwin's bin folder including the share folder in the cygwin folder in order for it to work.

When I do cmake --version it displays cmake version 3.4.1 correctly and it seems to be working. However when I use the following command I'm getting a few errors:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" . ..\third_party\ycmd\cpp
```

This command is the one I should be using to compile YCM under windows as stated in the docs. (without c autocomplete because I can't compile LLVM correctly under cygwin)
However it seems that it doesn't pick up the right compiler nor the right python version. I'm getting the following error:

```
Your C++ compiler does NOT support C++11, compiling in c++03 mode.
CMake Error at C:/cygwin64/share/cmake3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
    Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    (Required is at least version "2.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/cygwin64/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    C:/cygwin64/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:264 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
    BoostParts/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)

--Configuring incomplete, errors occured!
See also: "C:/cygwin64/home/Hylke/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Does anybody know of an easier way to get YCM working under cygwin? Aren't there some pre-compiled versions out there that I may use?
Or... Could someone point me into the right direction on how to compile it correctly using visual studio 2013 community 64 bits.

I've already tried using this command to fix the compiler issue:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/gcc.exe" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/g++.exe" . ../third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

But that seems to give the same output.